# Trouble with React Wrapper for Non-React Plugin: Maintaining State in Callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I've encountered an issue while integrating a non-React plugin into a React app via a wrapper component. The primary challenge arises with maintaining the correct state within the callbacks triggered by the plugin-generated elements.

Firstly, here's a simplified demonstration of the non-React plugin and its wrapper:

```
// Non-React Plugin
export interface MyPluginSettings {
  container: string;
  someCallback: () => void;
}

class MyPlugin {
  settings: MyPluginSettings;

  start(settings: MyPluginSettings) {
    const domElement = document.getElementById(settings.container);
    if (domElement) {
      const newButton = document.createElement("button");
      newButton.textContent = "I will trigger `someCallback`!";
      newButton.addEventListener("click", settings.someCallback);
      domElement.appendChild(newButton);
    }
  }
}

export { MyPlugin };
```

```
// Wrapper Component
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MyPlugin, MyPluginSettings } from "./MyPlugin";

interface MyPluginWrapperProps {
  configuration: MyPluginSettings;
}

const MyPluginWrapper = ({ configuration }: MyPluginWrapperProps) => {
  const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!started) {
      setStarted(true);
      const plugin = new MyPlugin();
      plugin.start(configuration);
    }
  }, [configuration, started]);

  return <div id="plugin-container" />;
};

export { MyPluginWrapper };
```

Finally, in my React application, I utilize this wrapper component:

```
import { MyPluginWrapper } from "./MyPluginWrapper";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Increment Counter</button>
      <span>{"The counter is at " + counter}</span>
      <MyPluginWrapper
        configuration={{
          container: "plugin-container",
          someCallback: () => {
            alert("the counter is " + counter);
          },
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**The Problem**

When the button generated by the plugin is clicked, an alert displays "the counter is 0", regardless of any subsequent increments to the counter triggered by the React app's button.

I suspect this might be due to closure-related issues. How can I effectively maintain the correct state within the callback functions triggered by the plugin-generated elements? In this simplified example, the issue persists despite correctly updating the state using React's useState hook.

Please note that while this example focuses on a single callback and state, in reality, there are multiple callbacks utilizing various states passed to the plugin. Any guidance on resolving this in a scalable and clean manner would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Solution 1**

One solution is to add a ref that is updated using a useEffect but is not very scalable.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
const counterRef = useRef(0)
useEffect(() => { counterRef.current = counter }, [counter])

// ...

return (
  <MyPluginWrapper
    configuration={{
      container: "plugin-container",
      someCallback: () => {
        alert("the counter is " + counterRef.current);
      },
    }}
  />
)
```

**Solution 2**

Another solution would be to use the wrapper as follows, but is not usable for props or values coming from other hooks.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

//...

return (
  <MyPluginWrapper
     configuration={{
       container: "plugin-container",
       someCallback: () => {
         setCounter(counter => {
            alert("the counter is " + counter);          
            return counter
         })
       },
    }}
  />
)
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-grass-9tl7nw?file=%2Fsrc%2FMyPluginWrapper.tsx%3A17%2C20